# Grails: background thread plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a doubt, Do I need to delete a background thread when the execute is done? Or the thread is automatically clean and deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java and Groovy, object instances are automatically garbage-collected when there's no more reference to them.

The Background Thread Plugin doesn't hold references to `Runnable`s or closures you pass to it (let's call them "threads") once those have been executed.

However, you shouldn't hold large arrays of references to these "threads" in instance variables at the class level. (I guess, you wouldn't do, anyway.) Remember that Services in Grails are *singleton-scoped* and have the same life span as the Grails application.
In contrast, object instances at the method level are garbage-collected after the method call has completed.

*After all, there's simply no need to delete "threads", just don't store the them in instance variables.*